# How to find the interface id of an interface which is in the included type library?

Tags: c++, dll, interface, firebreath

In my firebreath project i included the required dll in my project like this

```
#import "C:\Program Files\Avaya\AvayaOneXControls\my.dll", no_namespace,aw_interfaces_only
```

I need to use the iid of some of the interfaces defined in the dll.

How will i be able to find and use the type iids?

I even have the source code and .idl code of the dll.Can i find my required information from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile once after you add the import statement.

In your Debug or Release folder in your project you should see a **my.tlh** file.

This is like a C++ header file and should contain all the IID's for all the interfaces.